# How to remove javascript in vaadin when my application on mobile

Tags: vaadin

How to remove js function in vaadin when my application on mobile device.

```
     getCurrent().getPage().addBrowserWindowResizeListener(listener -> {
        if (listener.getWidth() < 480) {
            // Disable js function ... 
        } else {

        }
    });
```

Comment: As a new SO member, I would suggest please go through this section [MCVE]

Comment: What do you wish to do with removing JS ? Vaadin is JS based, so I don't see what you wish to show to the user on small screens

Comment: I use elevate zoom on my application when its(browser) resize maximum width less than 480px disable this js